# To use Facebook Javascript or not

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I'm planning to start a web app that uses the Facebook Python SDK. I found two examples in the sdk, newsfeed and oauth. Since im going to deploy  the app at google appengine I'm confused to choose which one to base my project. The oauth example uses OAuth 2.0 directly and the newsfeed example rely on the cookie saved by the Facebook Javascript SDK to get the user id of active user. Which one of the two examples will you prefer if you want your app to be less cpu intensive?

Comment: Neither of them should use a significant amount of CPU, as far as I know.

Comment: You mean whether to use the cookie or just send the user to Facebook to get the access code? I had the same dilemma, my logic tells me that a cookie means less back and forth between the user and Facebook servers, so I went with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would think newsfeed, but if there is a difference, it's very small.

Answer (score 0):

If is a Javascript SDK then it runs on the client browser, not in GAE server, so, that should be the one with less ( server ) CPU usage.